# POST controller can't download DOMPDF

Tags: codeigniter, post, dompdf, codeigniter-4

I have a problem on my code. So, I use DOMPDF on my controller with method POST, this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers; use CodeIgniter\Controller; use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class PdfController extends Controller {
    // public function __construct(){
    //     parent::__construct();
    // }
    public function index()
    {
        return view('slip-layout');
    }
    public function generateSlip()
    {
        $result = $this->request->getJsonVar('data');
        $filename = $result->name . "_" . $result->period->month . "_" . $result->period->year . "|" . date('y-m-d-H-i-s');
        $data = array(
            'd' => $result,
        );

        // instantiate and use the dompdf class
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();

        // load HTML content
        $dompdf->loadHtml(view('slip-layout', $data));

        // (optional) setup the paper size and orientation
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

        // render html as PDF
        $dompdf->render();

        // output the generated pdf
        $dompdf->stream($filename);

    } 
}
```

and this is how I call the API:

```
$("#form-submit").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch("/generate/slip", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ data: { ...allResult } }),
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
  });
});
```

The request is fine but the response is a bit strange like this

```
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
....
```

Any idea what is wrong with my code? Anyway I use codeigniter 4.
Thank you!

**EDIT: Sorry but I think the real question is why the pdf not downloading on POST request but it perfectly fine on GET request?**

Comment: Please share more details, like the code **in text form** and your attempts to resolve the problem. Did you check whether the response contains the proper header?

Comment: Also, as this is tagged with [tag:post]: would it work different when using a GET request?

Comment: @NicoHaase thank you for your response.
Yes if I use GET request it work perfectly, the reason why I use POST is to pass the data from view to the controller(the json data is quite big)

Comment: @NicoHaase I think the header is already proper, because there is no error on the response, the issue is just the DOMPDF download script cannot running at all(the last line of the screenshot)

Comment: "I think the header is already proper" - are you sure? When inspecting the headers in your browser, which ContentType is set? Can you share the code involved that sets the header? Keep in mind that all code should be shared **in text form**, not hidden in images.

Comment: @NicoHaase this is the response and request header https://imgur.com/a/5h897Aq
and this is how I hit the endpoint https://imgur.com/j0DkCbb
I'm not sure what in text form mean actually, I just do a normal JSON call API
Thank you

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question by editing it**, not to the comment section. Also, share the code you are using **in text form**, not screenshots of your code

Comment: "response is a bit strange" - what do you mean by that? Doesn't that look like a PDF header?

Comment: @NicoHaase ah yes, I mean I expect it to download the pdf not display it on the response

Comment: Where's the code for that? Do you really want to download the file over AJAX? Why did you use `console.log` then? Please check once more for the root problem: generating the PDF file might be fine, or not?

Comment: @NicoHaase I expect the `$dompdf->stream($filename);` downloading the pdf since when I use GET method it does so..
the console log just to handle the response, I didn't mean to download the pdf on the View side, I expect it from the Controller side